# Group account on google play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Is there on google play some group account? I mean: I have developed some application with friend and we would like to release on google play but with both of us? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *Group Account* on Google Play for developers.

That being said, you can add more than one user to an existing or new Developer account.

**Using the old interface:**

In the old interface, you can add more users to an account by using the *Manage user accounts* link (top right below the Google Play logo).

**Using the new interface:**

In the new interface, the same can be achieved using the Settings Icon in the left sidebar and then in the *User Accounts and Rights*

Refer to the [Support Document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en&ref_topic=16285) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add as many developer to single Google play account